# Building project with clang-cl in VS2019

Tags: c++, visual-studio, clang, c++17

I'm trying to build a project with `clang-cl` in Visual Studio 2019 checking `C++17` option in the project's properties. And I get the warning:

> constexpr if is a C++17 extension [-Wc++17-extensions]

I suppose that it should appear only for code that is not compiled as `C++17`. So why do I get this? Is the code compiled as `C++17`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility is that you have a different Standard selected for your project and an individual source file in that project. Try checking the "Language" option in the property sheet for the 'offending' source file(s) – make sure it is also set to use the C++17 Standard.